# Setting background colour of view not working

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, background-color

I am trying to size the view programatically, so that it looks good on all device sizes, but I am having trouble getting started.

I have a view set out on the main.storyboard with horizontally and vertically centred constraints.

I have the following code in the `viewDidLoad()` method:

```
centerView.frame.size.width = 2/3 * view.frame.width

centerView.frame.size.height = 2/3 * view.frame.height

centerView.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
```

The view does not have a background colour when I launch the app. What is the problem here?

Comment: Use: `centerView.backgroundColor = .blue`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing constraints with frames.. You can't do it like that.. Most likely, your view isn't sized correctly so you're not seeing the background colour even though it's there.. Check your view size in the view hierarchy inspector.

**Option 1:** Keep mixing constraints with frames:

```
func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    centerView.frame.size.width = 2.0/3.0 * view.frame.width
    centerView.frame.size.height = 2.0/3.0 * view.frame.height
    centerView.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
}
```

This sets your view's frame after everything has been laid out. It must be done in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` or in `layoutSubviews` of a subclass.

**Option 2:** Keep using only constraints

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    centerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 2.0 / 3.0, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
    centerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 2.0 / 3.0, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
    centerView.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
}
```

**Option 3:** Do it in the storyboard.. you can do a multiplier of `2.0 / 3.0` and set background colour there..